# Issue Converting Bytes to an Image from a PDF file

Tags: arrays, vb.net, bitmap, memorystream

I am trying to convert a pdf file to a Bitmap by first getting the Bytes of the PDF file and then converting it into a MemoryStream to Be converted into the Bitmap.

This worked successfully when converting images but not working with a pdf.

```
                Dim bytes As Byte() = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("C:\Users\s.ferry\Downloads\test2.pdf")

                Dim myimage As Image
                Dim msPdf As System.IO.MemoryStream = New System.IO.MemoryStream(bytes)
                myimage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(msPdf)

                upBmp = myimage
```

Above is the code snippet I am using to try and accomplish this. I am getting an error on the last line to say the parameter msPdf is not valid[See Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgxNw.png)

I was hoping to accomplish this without having to introduce a 3rd party source but don't think I will have a choice.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I'm not sure why you thought you could turn a PDF file into an `Inage`. Code like that will work for image files, e.g. JPG or BMP files. You can't just create an `Image` object from data that doesn't represent an image.

Comment: I don't think you can convert an image inside a PDF file directly, since they have different file formats. You need to extract the image first before using `MemoryStream` or `ImageConverter`.

Comment: Yeah I think I was clutching at straws tbh but i have conceded now to usig a 3rd party library with Spire.PDF. [Spire.PDF LINK](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/pdf-for-net-introduce.html)

Comment: For an understanding of why the System.Drawing.Image approach won't work, see [PDF Anatomy 101](http://www.planetpdf.com/developer/article.asp?ContentID=pdf%5Fanatomy%5F101%5F&gid=6351).

Answer (score 0):

I Don't think this is possible without a third party Library.

A useful and free tool for this is Spire.PDF

[More Info Here](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/pdf-for-net-introduce.html#.W3VVB-hKi70)

Answer (score 0):

It's understandable that you might think you could create an instance of the System.Drawing.Image class from a PDF directly.  In many cases a PDF document consists of a single-page that is no more than a scanned image so some users have the perspective that it's nothing more than an image format.

But most PDFs are much more complicated than this.  Online you will find a plethora of PDF software, however Rasterization of a PDF page to an image is a very complicated task that many vendors don't always do correctly.